# My program doesn't run on other computers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

So, recently I've created a program in visual studio 2010 using c++/cli. But the problem is, everytime I try to run the debug file on other computer , it just doesn't start. I tried to create another program on another computer and it worked. Can the problem be in the fact, that I have visual studio 2015 installed in this computer ? And if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check that you have the same libraries/dlls installed?

Comment: How can I check that ? I'm pretty new to all this stuff

Comment: You must build the Release version.  Also install [the C++ redist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug build uses a different C library than the release compile does. If you want to run your program on a different machine, make sure it's the release compile, and make sure the C++ runtime redistributable is installed.

- [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 x86 redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
- [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 x64 redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)